# Не могу правильно скомпоновать виджеты Label и TextBrowser

Tags: qtcreator, qt

В Qt Creator с помощью дизайнера разместил два виджета (`Label` и `TextBrowser`) в главном окне MainWindow:

[image]

Мне надо сделать так, чтобы после того как пользователь развернет программу на весь экран, виджет `Label` растянется только по горизонатали, а `TextBrowser` по горизонатали и вертикали.
Пробовал использовать разные сочитания `Vertical Layout`, `Horizontal Layout` и `Grid Layout`. Для `Label` установил sizePolicy = fixed. Пробовал как с помощью дизайнера так и прям из кода, но увы должного эффекта добиться не смог.
В проекте виджеты расположены следующим образом:

[image]

Если добавить виджет `Vertical Layout` и туда положит `Label` и `TextBrowser`.  То это работа на половину - если манипулировать отдельно виджетом `Vertical Layout`. Надо теперь `Vertical Layout` как-то привязать к главному окну `MainWindow`. Как показано внизу, они сейчас отделенны друг от друга:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас label и textbrowser не добавлены в лэйаут.

1. Установить для label sizePolicy по-вертикали в fixed.
2. Добавить в вертикальный лэйаут label и textbrowser.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, согласно замечанию.

Comment: 1. Выделяете centralWidget
2. На панели инструментов (сверху) выбираете вертикальный лэйаут

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало.